# Dynamics CRM Web API Bulk

Tags: c#, bulk, dynamics-crm-2016

All,

I have a C# program that is able to send data to a CRM system (by using the Web API through HTTP Post requests). However, amount of requests that I have to perform is in the order of 10000's on daily basis which as expected takes a huge amount of time to complete. I've been looking at a "bulk" functionality where I would be able to send a large amount of data at once (say 10000 task objects at once). For one reason or another I can't find such functionality being implemented, the closest I've gotten is ["batch requests"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607719.aspx) though by the example provided it looks like multiple requests wrapped in a single http post request, which, i am not quite sure would be the best solution for having generated 10000 post requests wrapped in a single such one unless this is the only way to do it

So, is there a bulk functionality or is the batch requests the best I have to deal with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the batching won't help you much since all of your requests will still be processed sequentially.  For that volume of data, you need to implement concurrency/parallelism/multi-threading.  The integration guy on my project has been able to achieve about 100 operations per second on average using what is essentially a producer/consumer pattern.  He uses an auto-growing pool of CRM connections and as soon as one request is finished processing, the connection is returned to the pool.

The Microsoft Premier Field Engineering team publishes the [PFE Core Library for Dynamics CRM](https://pfexrmcore.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.  The library has a [ParallelOrganizationServiceProxy](https://pfexrmcore.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ParallelOrganizationServiceProxy%20Class) class that should do a lot of the complicated concurrency work for you.   Here's an example:

```cs
public void ParallelUpdate(List<Entity> targets)
{
    try
    {
        this.Manager.ParallelProxy.Update(targets);
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        // Handle exceptions
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Polsh, Thanks for the reply! Hmm .. one would have expected microsoft to release a bulk functionality for a REST API wouldn't you agree? I've been trying to avoid the "old" or "3rd party" libraries so far but I guess the task is in-feasible without them, even with though, as it seems multi-threading is likely the best choice... How about this one then, are you familiar ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863631.aspx

Comment: ExecuteMultiple is the equivalent of batching in the WebAPI. It also has another major drawback: the platform will only process two ExecuteMultiple requests at any given time. :/

Comment: By the way, isn't the batch request sending all at once and then the separate ones executed on the crm side thus reducing the latency of the separate connections? Otherwise I don't see the idea of it?

Comment: You got it. It's most helpful in high latency environments where the network is the biggest bottleneck.

Comment: I see, thank you! :) So just write the obvious down .. the batch request will speed up the process it just won't be simultaneous as with a bulk functionality?